# Jquery Ajax redirect success state not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to redirect the user to google.com after ajax success state but when the ajax completed successfully the success function not working or not called at all 
the code of ajax is

```
$('.modal2c').click(function() {
    //  event.preventDefault();
    var urlpost = "<?php echo $post_url; ?>";
    var username1 = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var magic = document.getElementById("magic").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: urlpost,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            username: username1,
            password: password1,
            magic: magic
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('data');
            window.location.href("https://www.google.com")
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: check your **developer** tools console ... `window.location.href is not a function` - and do *try* to post legible well formatted code

Comment: to be clear ... the issue is that `window.location.href is not a function`

Answer (score -2):

Can you please add some more info about you problem. please Add Error block in Ajax to get exact reason to know why this happens.

```
$('.modal2c').click(function () {
       //  event.preventDefault();
var urlpost = "<?php echo $post_url; ?>";
var username1 = document.getElementById("username").value;  
var password1 =document.getElementById("password").value ;
        var magic   =document.getElementById("magic").value;    

                 $.ajax({

    url:urlpost,  
           method:"POST", 
    data:{username:username1,password:password1,magic:magic},  

  success:function(data){alert('data');
                window.location.href("https://www.google.com")   

            },
             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
 }); }   


   );
```

Comment: @JaromandaX, Actually I want to add a comment for this. But due to less reputation I was unable to Add comment there. In my answer, I just added Error block of AJAX. & I didn't find any issues with formatting

Comment: I just added Error Block, I haven't play with orignal Code

Comment: @JaromandaX, As I said Earlier, I don't have enough reputation to comment on actual post

Comment: when I update my code the alert message not showing any thing  the only thing  shich showing is alert(XMLHttpRequest.status)=0

Comment: my problem is  I can not make redirect after ajax send data to the handler page I want to make redirect after success but there is any thing happening

Comment: when I put alert in error function the alert is showing but when put   window.location.href("https://www.google.com")   
there is nothing happen